# Subtract second column from two matrices based on first column

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Let say I have 2 matrices `A` (7x2) and `B` (3x2)

```
A = [1 5;2 6;3 7;4 8;5 9;6 10;7 11]  
B = [2 4;4 7;5 3]
```

The result that I want is:

```
C = [2 2;4 1;5 6]
```

Comment: Does the first col of `A` always have the form 1, 2, 3...? You should specify that, or choose a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want [intersect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)
that way it will work even if A doesn't have to be in order or have all numbers from 1.

```
A = [1 5;2 6;3 7;4 8;5 9;6 10;7 11]
B = [2 4;4 7;5 3]

[cc,ia,ib] = intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1))
C = [cc,A(ia,2)-B(ib,2)]
```

Comment: Also +1 for not assuming `A(:,1)` is a not necessarily a row index. I'm partial to `ismember`, but `intersect` conveniently gives you `cc`, so it's pretty good here.

Comment: Thanks vish, this _intersect_ works for my real case.

Answer (score 3):

`ismember` does the job too:

```
>> C = [B(:,1) A(ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)),2) - B(:,2)]
C =
     2     2
     4     1
     5     6
```

Or if not all of `B(:,1)` is in `A`:

```
[m,locs] = ismember(B(:,1),A(:,1))
C = [A(locs,1) A(locs,2) - B(m,2)]
```

Comment: +1 for not assuming that first col of `A` is necessarily of the form in the example (bad chosen example, anyway). -- Or, are you?